# Why was this question closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, policy

I was surprised to see that [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/252633/how-do-i-force-mathematica-to-output-more-digits-for-this-particular-expression), on doing a calculation of Pi with high precision, was closed as off-topic.

The justification for closing questions as off-topic is, according to the [help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions):

> This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

which surely does not apply here as the author explicitly mentioned:

> I'm evaluating the below expression in Mathematica...

> I have read the documentation pertaining to the use of arbitrary precision, and the function N[expr, n]

and also discusses his/her attempts using Mathematica:

> the output for my particular expression returns 3.141592653589793 which is only 16 digit accuracy...

> I have used the function NumberForm such that Mathematica displays all the digits it has stored.

Also, the question has a well-defined answer using Mathematica (see my [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/252636/61267)). Hence, as I do not have voting privileges in the Mathematica stack yet, I would like to petition that it is reopened.

Comment: It wasn't closed as off-topic per se but rather as coming from such a simple error that the answer should be possible to find in the documentation. Their issue was using `.5` instead of `1/2` when trying to get to an arbitrary precision result and that kind of problem is addressed very often/early in the documentation. It's also notable that they were still given an answer in the comments. Your answer is great, but the problem the OP was really asking about just isn't a great fit for the site since just reading a tutorial would have gotten them to the answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response.